# Is JavaScript able to substitute php?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, web-services, alternate

I have a friend who started learning website development and he's into php now. I, on the other side started studying Javascript. He asked me if it's possible to use JS instead of php code *entirely*?

Well, I started learning JS because someone told me, it can be used for both frontend, backend (via NodeJS) and the database (via MongoDB). Though, since I' m a beginner in this field, I'm not sure in the answer, and I'm interested anyway, so I ask you: is it possible?

Comment: nodejs can be used on the server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> He asked me if it's possible to use JS instead of php code entirely?

Yes, it's entirely possible. There are several server-side JavaScript options. Probably the most well-known is [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org) (usually, but not necessarily, plus [Express](http://expressjs.com)). But Microsoft has always supported JScript (their dialect of JavaScript) in classic ASP, you can use JavaScript in the Java JVM (via Rhino or Nashorn) and thus use JavaScript in servlets, for years there was SilkJS (built on Google's V8) and now there's its successor [DecafJS](https://github.com/decafjs/decaf) (built on the JVM), etc.